# How to build a data flow?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, dataflow

I am running Visual Studio 2008, the SSIS Tutorial described on:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167106.aspx

I finished all of the tasks but am getting following errors:

> Error  1   Validation error. Extract Sample Currency Data: Extract Sample Currency Data: input column "CurrencyAlternateKey" (123) has lineage ID 55 that was not previously used in the Data Flow task.   Lesson 1.dtsx   0   0
>       Error   2   Validation error. Extract Sample Currency Data SSIS.Pipeline: input column "CurrencyAlternateKey" (123) has lineage ID 55 that was not previously used in the Data Flow task.   Lesson 1.dtsx   0   0

Can you tell what I need to do to make this build without errors?

Answer (score 5):

I often will get this error if I copied a data flow and pasted it to create another data flow, and then made some modifications to it. SSIS doesn't like copying and pasting often times, especially data flows.

Comment: Yeah, the generated linking IDs that get used in the XML are not amenable to C&P at all.

Comment: I'd upvote that a ton of times if I could. Cut and paste of dataflow has always turned out to take me more time than creating from scratch. It's silly but true.